# Null values in deselect checkbox Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, redmine

In my application, if the User must deselect all check box him informed, be saved or a `null Array []`.

I'm using `params[: parameter1] [: parametro2_ids] | | = []` after booting my Action UPDATE, however if I try to clear all the rails in the log returns:

`NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil: NilClass):`. In normal logic, it should be functional. How can I implement a function if it is not checked or unchecked all worthless?

`responsabilities_controller`

```
class ResponsabilitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @responsabilities = Responsability.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @responsabilities }
    end
  end

  def show
    @responsability = Responsability.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @responsability }
    end
  end


  def new
    @responsability = Responsability.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @responsability }
    end
  end


  def edit
    @responsability = Responsability.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create

    @responsability = Responsability.new(params[:responsability])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @responsability.save

        format.html {
          flash[:notice] = l(:notice_success)
          redirect_to :contoller => "uc_rh",:action => "index"
        }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @responsability.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update

      params[:responsability][:knowledge_ids] || [] if params[:responsability].present?
      params[:responsability][:competence_ids] || [] if params[:responsability].present?
      params[:responsability][:tool_ids] || [] if params[:responsability].present?

    @responsability = Responsability.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @responsability.update_attributes(params[:responsability])

        format.html {
          flash[:notice] = l(:notice_success_edit)
          redirect_to :contoller => "responsabilities",:action => "edit"
        }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @responsability.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy

    @responsability = Responsability.find(params[:id])
    @responsability.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to responsabilities_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  def nested_knowledges
    @responsability = Responsability.find(params[:id])

  end


  def nested_competences
    @responsability = Responsability.find(params[:id])
  end


  def nested_tools
    @responsability = Responsability.find(params[:id])
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this code

```
params[:parameter1][:parametro2_ids] ||= [] if params[:parameter1].present?
```

Comment: ,Thank you for your consideration, but the code in my controller applied resulted in no change. Keeps popping up that error ... I could use some method to validate if they are null and delete records from the table?

Comment: use params[:responsability][:knowledge_ids] ||= [] if params[:responsability].present?
now code return params[:parameter1][:parametro2_ids] or []

Comment: also you can try set at the beginning of the method
return false unless params[:parameter1].present?

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil: NilClass) for params[:parameter1][:parametro2_ids] ||= [] means: you have nil params[:parameter1] and call method [:parametro2_ids] for nil class